# Why is it that reactions that cause an increase of temperature are exothermic?

Tags: heat, enthalpy

I've been taught that if you have two aqueous reactants that react together and produce heat it is exothermic. Shouldn't that be endothermic? Did my professor misspeak?

If it's gaining heat, that means it's pulling heat from the outside. The opposite of what happens when water freezes and releases heat (which is actually exothermic).

Comment: Also, is the "break down of for during digestion" endothermic or exothermic?

It requires energy to break bonds, so I think it's endothermic, but it also releases heat supposedly.

Comment: When you burn something, does _the thing_ actually become cooler and the area around it become hotter? Or does it all become hotter?